# Get inner array of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
 Array (
                [0] => Array 
                (
                    [example] => 'h'
                )
                [1] => Array 
                (
                    [example] => 'e'
                ) 
                [2] => Array 
                (
                    [example] => 'l'
                )
                [3] => Array 
                (
                    [example] => 'p'
                )
        )
```

And I am wondering how can I change this array to look like this instead.

```
Array( [example] => 'h', [example] => 'e', [example] => 'l', [example] => 'p')
```

I have tried using a nested foreach loop but using that I only get the values and not as an array.

Comment: You can't change it to look the way you want, because that entails duplicate keys (`example`)

Comment: What do you want to have as keys? [example] is obviously duplicated in your expected result and thus cannot be used as a key. Are the inner arrays num-indexed or do you need to preserve their keys as well? (@MarkBaker is comment-ninja)

Comment: Well the thing is I do want to preserve their keys because I want to use it in an SQL statement, are you saying there is no way to convert it to how I would like it?

Comment: Not to how you like it, but something like `Array ( [example] => Array( [0] => 'h', [1] => 'e', [2] => 'l', [3] => 'p') )` can be done.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to reach the values of a multidimensional array:

```
$array = array(
    0=>array('example'=>'h'),
    1=>array('example'=>'e'),
    2=>array('example'=>'l'),
    3=>array('example'=>'p')
);
```

1, If looping through the array:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value['example'];
}
```

2, Call a value directly:

```
echo $array[0]['example'];
echo $array[1]['example'];
echo $array[2]['example'];
echo $array[3]['example'];
```

---

It is impossible to create an array the way that you mentioned (having 4 'example' as keys). Take the following for example:

```
$array['example'] = 'h';
$array['example'] = 'e';
$array['example'] = 'l';
$array['example'] = 'p';
echo $array['example'];
```

The output would be `p` because you are simply overwriting the variable `$array['example']` each time.

Comment: Oh ok then, thank you I will have to rethink my code to get it the way I want it.